# How to duplicate data in relation table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently, I have 2 tables:

- Table A (`master`) with 3 columns: tblA (`tblA_ID`,  `name`, desc) (`tblA_ID` is identity key)
- Table B (`detail`) with 4 columns: tblB (`tblB_ID`,  `tblA_ID`,  `name`, desc)

`Table A` has 100 records, every record has 10 records at table B in relationship.

What I want is to add 1.000.000 records to Table 2 for each of these 100 tblA_IDs. Or rather, add 999.990 records for each tblA_IDs, since Table B already has 10 records for each of those IDs.

My solution is using the `cursors`, get one-by-one in table A, with each `tblA_ID`, get it, find its data at table B and insert into both tables then.

So, is it possible? Do you have any suggestion to solve this case ?

Comment: What do you mean by " insert into both tables then" If the tables already have the records in Table A and Table B, why do you want to insert the same records into the tables again?

Comment: Could you please specify what DBMS (and probably what version thereof) you are using?

Comment: @InSane: They seem to want to duplicate the rows intentionally, as per their post's title.

Comment: If you have 10 records in table b for each of the 100 records of table a, you'll only have 1000 records in table B. What do you mean by 1.000.000 records?

Comment: @Andriy - Aaahh..i see it now. My brain was just failing to recognize it earlier even though I read it as it just didnt make any sense to me as to why - but - maybe all he is trying to do is simulate data for some performance test. Thanks.

Comment: @AndriyM: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine: you said correct, 1.000.000 records is just the generate number.

Answer (score 0):

From what i'm trying to understand, It seems like you are trying to insert dummy data for testing. There are some software available to accomplish what you are after. One which I found to be extremely good is:

RedGate SQL Data Generator: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/

This has a 14 day trial to test it out.

There are some free options available but not as good, since redgate's software handles table relationships on it's own.

One of the free generators is: http://www.generatedata.com

You can download a csv file and add it to your tables by right clicking on the database, hover on **Tools**, and click on **Import data**

Comment: yes, thank you but it is not what I'm looking for. Because my database already has these 2 tables, and they are using now.

Comment: So in table A you want to keep 100 records, and you want to replicate the amount of rows in table 2 to 1,000,000, having the ID of tblA_ID?